# Why need to add a $ sign after url?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am wactching a video about Django rest framework. The guy adds a dollar sign $ after a URL and said this is better but he never explain why. So anybody knows why we need to add it?
[image]

Comment: It's a regular expression that has a begining with ^ and ends with $... so match a URL that starts with users and ends with /.

Answer (score 2):

In python regex, the dollar sign represents an exact path match. If you have `r'^users'` with no dollar sign at the end, that will tell your urls.py file to match any path that begins with 'users' to go to the corresponding route. `r'^users$'` prevents the route 'users/create' etc from being directed to your views.usersView.as_view() method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Clear and easy understand.